# c3 js pie chart from csv

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'm trying to display a pie chart using C3.js loading data from a CSV. I'm able to get the chart to display my data when it's manually input. But I can't figure out how to get the chart to load properly from the CSV. Is there a way to tell the pie chart that the first column is a label and the second column is the data to be displayed from the CSV?

Here's where I'm at:

```
var summary = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['0-1',42.11],
            ['1-3',33.80],
            ['3-5',6.94],
            ['5-10',3.99],
            ['10-2',10.05],
            ['>20',3.11]
        ],
        type: 'pie'
    },
    size: {
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    }
})

setTimeout(() => {
    c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
            url: 'data.csv',
            type: 'pie'
        },
        size: {
            width: 500,
            height: 500
        }
    });
}, 1000)
```

My CSV

```
Name,Percentage
0-1,42.11
1-3,33.80
3-5,6.94
5-10,3.99
10-20,10.05
>20,3.11
```

What the chart is supposed to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/koymo.png

How it's loading from the CSV:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFmLc.png

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I used Papaparse to parse the CVS data into the correct format. Here's how to display a pie chart from a CSV using C3.js (also had to change columns to rows):

```
function parseData(createGraph) {
    Papa.parse("data.csv", {
        download: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            createGraph(results.data);
        }
    });
}


function createGraph(data) {
    var name = [];
    var percentage = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        name.push(data[i][0]);
        percentage.push(data[i][1])
    }
    
    console.log(name);
    console.log(percentage);
    
    var summary = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart',
            data: {
                rows: [
                    name,
                    percentage
                ],
                type: 'pie'
            },
            legend: {
                show:false
            }
    });

}

parseData(createGraph);
```